# DBT (Data Build Tool)-Update Syntax in dbt model

Tags: dbt

It might be simple question and I'm new to DBT.

I have one.sql file in DBT and it is inserting data into table TARGET.

I want to update table TARGET based on SORUCE table as below condition. I tried to place another sql file second.sql and it is not updating.

How to convert below sql into DBT model. Can you please help.

```
UPDATE TARGET S
SET S.FLAG='N'
FROM SOURCE T
WHERE S.FLAG='Y' AND S.ID=T.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

dbt model files, like the `one.sql` you're describing should contain the `SELECT` statement to make the TARGET table. The statement should always produce the correct table(or other materialization) when the model file is run. `UPDATE` statements are not needed.

When the SOURCE(s) that `one.sql` depends on are changed then the `one.sql` file should be run again to update the values in it. How it knows to run depends on a number of things outside the scope of this question. Whether the underlying database code does a DROP and re-CREATE table, incrementalism, or something else depends on the `materialization:` set for the model.

To be clear, dbt doesn't support running UPDATE statements. They're not supported on purpose. They're anti-antithetical to what dbt is trying to enable, such as lineage and accuracy.